# C# Scriptcs module won't load

Tags: module, scriptcs

Hi guys I'm discovering scriptcs modules authoring, I followed the tuto https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/wiki/Modules by letter 
and I suppose at the execution time when loading my module to display Hello World as it is discribed in the tuto the build is ok 0 errors but nothing happens when I browse to the directory where the module is tested and try to execute scriptcs -modules [my module name as defined in the Module attribute]

am I missing a detail thank you
1:06:27 PM
 bechir
Is there anyne there khellang for example?
1:14:02 PM
just to know if someone is here to know wether I stay or Leave

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, I found that I have to upload the module and then install it with the `-g` option.

```
scriptcs install -modules modulename -g
```

It couldn't be tested directly as I did.